# Audio tags added with ffmpeg do not show up in cmus

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, ffprobe, cmus

I run the following command:

```
 $ ffmpeg -i BabiYarHumor.wav -map 0 -y -codec copy -write_id3v2 1 -metadata "artist=Dmitri Shostakovich" -metadata "genre=Classical" -metadata "album=Symphony No. 13 \"Babi Yar\"" -metadata "title=Humor. Allegretto" -metadata "date=1962" -metadata "comment=Conductor: Rudolph Barshai, Orchestra: WDR Sinfonieorchester, Choir: The Choral Academy Moscow, Soloist: Sergei Aleksashkin" BabiYar.wav
```

The output of `ffprobe` on the output file:

```
 $ ffprobe BabiYar.wav
ffprobe version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.1.1 (GCC) 20230429
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883
--enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, wav, from '44-SymphonyNo13_in_B-Flat_Minor_for_Bass_ChorusOrchestra_Op._113_Babi_Yar_II._Humour._All-tagged.wav':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Dmitri Shostakovich
    comment         : Conductor: Rudolph Barshai, Orchestra: WDR Sinfonieorchester, Choir: The Choral Academy Moscow, Soloist: Sergei Aleksashkin
    date            : 1962
    genre           : Classical
    title           : Humor. Allegretto
    album           : Symphony No. 13 "Babi Yar"
    track           : 2
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:08:28.35, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

The issue is that `cmus` does not recognize any of my new tags. How can I add tags that `cmus` will recognize?